# Adjust Brush Opacity drag hotkey/shortcut?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, brush, shortcuts

I thought I read somewhere that there was a way to adjust the brush opacity interactively in CS6 (13) in the same way you adjust brush size and hardness (ie: Alt+Right-click and drag). In fact, the CS6 UI seems to support this, because it now shows a readout for Size, Hardness AND Opacity.

Of course, you can adjust brush opacity with the slider, and by typing the number directly on the keyboard, and in Prefs you can disable Hardness vertical HUD movement which then replaces it with Opacity.

But I want all three axes. Anyone know the trick? workaround? prayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe any such dynamic exists.

Opacity is only a dynamic option if you have a tablet which supports brush dynamics connected. I've never heard or seen any shortcut to adjust opacity other than the keyboard numbers.

Like you posted, disabling the hardness dynamic does allow for opacity dynamics. But, I don't think there's any method to directly adjust opacity dynamics with the hardness dynamic on.

Of course, you could use the **airbrush option** for the brush and the speed at which you paint will effect opacity.

The use of a tablet really takes brush dynamics to the next level, making them far more realistic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll leave this question open in case anyone has any other thoughts. I wonder whether any scripting exists that addresses this? though I doubt that's part of the API, but one can always hope..